# ExecuteScalar Error

Tags: sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

i keep getting error "NullReferenceException was unhandled. Object reference not set to an instance of an object" on line 5

```
1.    Private void textbox1_TextChanged(object sender,EventArgs e)
2     {
3.       SqlConnection cn=new SqlConnection("Connection string");
4.       String sql ="select name from bank_info where account_no ='"+textbox1.Text+"'";
5.       SqlCommand cmd =new SqlCommand(sql,cn);
6.       Cn.Open();
7.       String s1 = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
8.       TextBox2.Text =s1.ToString();
```

Am new to programming.Thanks

Comment: That error  "NullReferenceException was unhandled."   is not even close to your only error in that code

Comment: What other error please?

Comment: you understand people type pretty fast, and you're trying to make a connection to db every time the text is changed in the text box for start - as for the other errors , the answer from @Mr Moose fixed those

Answer (score 1):

Try something like the following. Your connection should noremally be created from your connection. Using statements are a good way of ensuring that classes that implement IDisposable have Dispose called. Use SqlParameters to avoid SQL Injection issues.

```
using(SqlConnection cn=new SqlConnection("Connection string"))
{
   cn.Open();

   String sql ="select name from bank_info where account_no = @accNo"; // '"+textbox1.Text+"'";

   using (SqlCommand cmd = cn.CreateCommand())
   {
       cmd.CommandText = sql;
       SqlParameter param = cmd.CreateParameter();
       param.ParameterName = "@accNo";
       param.Value = textbox1.Text;
       cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
       object obj = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
       TextBox2.Text = obj != null ? obj.ToString() : string.Empty;
   }

}
```

Comment: this fixes most issues in the code except for the nullreferenceexception he was asking about (which still happens if executescalar returns a null)

Comment: @Mr Moose-Am getting error (The name 'cn' does not exist in the current context) with cn.open() and cn.createcommand underlined with blue squigly line

Comment: It will be because I used uppercase C accidently. Cn is the variable you used to assign your connection to. I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This will help

```
 Private void textbox1_TextChanged(object sender,EventArgs e)
 {
   SqlConnection cn=new SqlConnection("Connection string");
   String sql ="select name from bank_info where account_no ='"+textbox1.Text+"'";
   SqlCommand cmd =new SqlCommand(sql,cn);
   Cn.Open();
   Object obj = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
   String s1 = (obj!=null)?(String)obj:"";
   TextBox2.Text =s1.ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot...u're a life saver

Answer (score -1):

Can you see the query in the dubug mode and see the sql. check running the same query in sql to see for that account number is returning you a result. if there are no results
to avoid exception you can check for DB Null which will not throw an exception.